# dropdown list using form_for [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

I have `User` model and there are boolean attributes `admin` , `employee` , `student` inside `User` model , how to make one of those attribute true if selected using a list box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <%= f.checkbox :admin %> Admin
  ...
```

This will create a form and a checkbox with name `user[admin]` and so on.

If you want checkboxes to be selected according the value in User instance remember to pass `@user`, where `@user = User.find(some_id)`

In your controller you will have:

```
def create # or def update
  @user = User.new params[:user] # or User.find
  if @user.save # or @user.update_attributes
    # handle success
  else
    # handle error
  end
end
```

Comment: okay , but what about if i want to make those attributes in a drop list ?? not a check box

Comment: If you want to do it in a dropdown list, your model maybe would be better with a `role` column instead of three boolean tags. You can change easily your view with `f.select`, `f.collection_select` BUT you will need to fit the parameters you are sending from view, suppose your select is: <select name="role">... you will send role="Admin" or role="Student", or you even could send role="1" or role="2" but this does not match with your data model: three  columns for one sent value